# PowerMockito working without PowerMockRunner?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit4, powermockito

I just used powermockito for the first time today and after running tests I realized that it disabled my code coverage(I now know that this is a known bug and there are workarounds such as rules)

As I played around with it, I took out the Runwith(powermockrunner.class) annotation and PrepareForTest annotation.

This gave me my coverage back but at the same time my static mocks are working fine as well.

This confuses me because from everything that I'be read online, I thought those annotations were necessary?

I'' using the following jars:

powermock-mockito-1.5.6
Junit-4.4
Mockito-all-1.9.5.

Comment: They are absolutely necessary in general, but tests can be written that don't require them, and other tests can look correct but be fragile or wrong in practice. Please post your code; I'd be surprised if your tests are working the way you think they are.

Comment: I have worked with Powermock quite a bit, and had to play around with quite a few combinations of Jar versions and properties for sonar, jacoco, powermock and mockito to get it working. Most of our unit Tests are using both those annotations and are still included in our coverage results. If you share your pom that has your jacoco plugin, and the test class thats not showing the coverage, I'll be able to help you figure it out.